# Exporting Contacts - Reporting?

Tags: custom-fields, export, reports, custom-reports, fields

Is there a way to save different reports? ie. the fields wanted to export? so you don't have to enter those in every single time you do an export?

Comment: The tags here are confusing, and if the question is about Exporting Contacts via the 'export' option then I would recommend you remove the word 'report' from title and tags, since CiviReports is a separate feature to Export (though yes you can 'export' from a Report' but the civi concept of 'export' is from the Actions dropdown that you get from a search. hth

Comment: I am new to this platform, and this database -- please kindly understand.

Comment: @SproutMediaLab welcome to CiviCRM! Glad you're here. Once you read through the user manual and try things out, please do come here with questions to clarify. It would be great to demonstrate that you've done some legwork by starting your question with "I read the chapter on Exporting and tried it out on the demo server but I have a question about..."

Answer (score 5):

If you mean exporting after doing eg a Search or Advanced Search, then on the screen where you select which fields to export, you can check a box to save that common set of fields for future exports (see image below). Then, the next time you go to do an export you can select to "Use Saved Field Mapping" and select the previously saved set of fields.

[image: Save field mapping]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean exporting data from a Report, then after selecting the fields on a report, you can click the Update Report to save those fields. Alternatively, you can click on the Save a Copy... button to leave the existing report as it is but make a new one with the new fields. Then when you export, those fields will be exported.